# Self-Adjoint extensions of a vector-valued operator

Tags: functional-analysis, isometry

I've been learning about self-adjoint extensions from volume 2 of the Reed and Simon book. I'm still quite a beginner at the material and I'm having trouble with even a simple example. To test my knowledge, I decided to try looking at the operator:
\begin{equation*}
H_0 = \left( \begin{array}{cc} 0 & 1 \\ -1 & 0 \end{array} \right) \frac{d}{dx} + \left( \begin{array}{cc} m & 0 \\ 0 & -m \end{array} \right)
\end{equation*}
With domain $\mathcal{D}(H_0) = \left\{ \phi \in C^\infty_0(\mathbb{R} \backslash \left\{0 \right\}: \phi(0^-)=a, \phi(0^+) = b) \right\}$ and $\phi:\mathbb{R} \backslash \left\{ 0 \right\} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}^2$. I'd like to calculate all self-adjoint extensions of this operator via two different methods. One is via direct calculation and the other is by utilizing isometries. Here's my attempt with direct calculation: \

Suppose $\hat{H}$ is a symmetric extension of $H_0$. Then we have for all $\phi \in \mathcal{D}(\hat{H})$ and $\psi \in \mathcal{D}(\hat{H}^*)$,
\begin{equation*}
\langle \hat{H} \phi, \psi \rangle = \langle \phi, \hat{H}^* \psi \rangle
\end{equation*}
Recalling the definition of $H_0$ and simplifying results in:
\begin{equation*}
\left\langle \left( \begin{array}{cc} 0 & 1 \\ -1 & 0 \end{array} \right) \phi_x , \psi \right\rangle = \left\langle \phi, \left( \begin{array}{cc} 0 & 1 \\ -1 & 0 \end{array} \right) \psi_x \right\rangle
\end{equation*}
Appealing to integration by parts and canceling equivalent terms on either side of the equality results in:
\begin{equation*}
\left( \begin{array}{cc} 0 & 1 \\ -1 & 0 \end{array} \right) \phi \cdot \psi \bigg|_{0^-}^{0^+}  =0
\end{equation*}
Since $\mathcal{D}(\hat{H}) \subseteq \mathcal{D}(\hat{H}^*)$ we must have $\forall \phi = \left( \begin{array}{c} \phi_1 \\ \phi_2 \end{array} \right) \in \mathcal{D}(\hat{H})$,
\begin{equation*}
\left( \begin{array}{c} \phi_2 \\ -\phi_1 \end{array} \right) \cdot \left( \begin{array}{c} \phi_1 \\ \phi_2 \end{array} \right) \bigg|_{0^-}^{0^+} = 0
\end{equation*}
This holds trivially for any choice of $\phi$ with defined limits at $0$. Thus this tells us no additional restrictions on the boundary conditions so I'm not sure what to do in this case. Thus I will look at the second method via isometries:

This method begins by determining the deficiency subspaces $\mathcal{H}_+(H_0)$ and $\mathcal{H}_-(H_0)$. Recall the definition $\mathcal{H}_-(H_0) = \ker(i+H_0^*)$. Thus we are interested in solving the following equation for $\phi \in \mathcal{D}(H_0)$:
\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
0 =& \left( i + H_0^* \right) \left( \begin{array}{c} \phi_1 \\ \phi_2 \end{array} \right) \\
=& \left( \begin{array}{c} m+i \\ -m + i \end{array} \right) \left( \begin{array}{c} \phi_1 \\ \phi_2 \end{array} \right) + \left( \begin{array}{c} \phi_2' \\ - \phi_1' \end{array} \right)
\end{split} 
\end{equation*}
This system is easily solved via the substitution method. We get
\begin{equation*}
\mathcal{H}_-(H_0) = \left\{ \left( \begin{array}{c} c_1 e^{\sqrt{m^2+1} x} + c_2 e^{-\sqrt{m^2+1} x} \\ \frac{c_1 \sqrt{m^2+1}}{-m+i} e^{\sqrt{m^2+1} x} + \frac{-c_2 \sqrt{m^2+1}}{-m+i} e^{- \sqrt{m^2+1} x} \end{array} \right) : c_1, c_2 \in \mathbb{C} \right\} 
\end{equation*}
Similar calculations will show that
\begin{equation*}
\mathcal{H}_+(H_0) = \left\{ \left( \begin{array}{c} c_1 e^{\sqrt{m^2+1} x} + c_2 e^{-\sqrt{m^2+1} x} \\\frac{c_1 \sqrt{m^2+1}}{-(m+i)} e^{\sqrt{m^2+1} x} + \frac{-c_2 \sqrt{m^2+1}}{-(m+i)} e^{- \sqrt{m^2+1} x} \end{array} \right) : c_1, c_2 \in \mathbb{C} \right\} 
\end{equation*}
Notice $\dim(\mathcal{H}_-(H_0))=\dim(\mathcal{H}_+(H_0)) = \dim(\mathbb{C} \times \mathbb{C}) = 4$. By Theorem X.2 (Reed Simon Vol. 2) if we can find a partial isometry $U$ from $\mathcal{H}_+$ into $\mathcal{H}_-$ then the corresponding closed symmetric extension $\hat{H}$ of $H_0$ has the following properties:
\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
&\mathcal{D}(\hat{H}) = \left\{ \phi +\phi_+ + U\phi_+ : \phi \in \mathcal{D}(H_0), \phi_+ \in I(U) \right\} \\
&\hat{H}(\phi + \phi_+ + U\phi_+) = H_0(\phi) + i \phi_+ - i U \phi_+
\end{split}
\end{equation*}
where $I(U)$ is the initial space of a partial isometry $U$. Furthermore the deficiency indices of $\hat{H}$ are
\begin{equation*}
n_{\pm}(\hat{H}) = n_{\pm}(H_0) - \dim[I(U)]
\end{equation*}
For $\hat{H}$ to be self-adjoint, we necessarily need $n_{\pm}(\hat{H}) =0$ and consequently we are looking for partial isometries $U$ with $\dim[I(U)] = n_{\pm}(H_0) = 4$. I'd like to know if I've made any mistakes up to here and how to find all such possible isometries. Thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: I assume you mean that the domain consists of functions for which the limits exist and can be anything? Otherwise, specifying the values to be specifically 'a' and 'b' will not give you a linear domain.